# Anaconda can't see pytrends

Tags: python, anaconda

Windows 10; installed Python 3.6.0, installed pytrends, then installed Anaconda 4.3.0 (Python 3.6, 64-bit).
Anaconda does not see my pytrends package: error "No module named 'pytrends'".
Pytrends is installed - Python Shells accepts "from pytrends.request import TrendReq".

Comment: `conda install` does not work either. Workaround - I copied packages manually, from python lib to Anaconda lib folder.

Answer (score 1):

You have two python installations, your original one and Anaconda's. They are independent and whatever module you add in one it is not available to the other. You have to do the pip install in your Anaconda python for it to have its own pytrends.

Answer (score 0):

Try with 'pip install pytrends' --> see https://github.com/GeneralMills/pytrends#installation for instructions